# Mathematical stuff are not appearing when making the font bigger in Latex

Tags: fonts

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
     \usepackage{amsthm}
   \usepackage{textcomp}
     \usepackage{dsfont}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{hhline}
   \usepackage{fancyvrb}

    \begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\large]
     $${r \choose r} + {r+1 \choose r} + {r+1 \choose r} + ..... + {n 
    \choose r} = {n+1 \choose r+1}   $$
   \end{Verbatim}

  we will prove this by using induction on n. \\
   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} = 1$$
```

as you can see in the picture it's not being displayed for some reason. Can someone help?

N.B: the stuff i wrote is far from done so don't judge me on that one :D

[image: pic]

Comment: You use verbatim, which displays code, not the result.

Comment: how can i fix that?

Comment: What do you want to fix? Don't use verbatim? Or do you want the code printed next to the output? Do you want to increase the math font size only for that part? What is your question?

Comment: in addition to other comments, never use `\\ ` before a math display.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle why not?

Comment: it destroys the layout, you should never use `\\ `at the end of any paragraph (including the partial paragraph before a display)  you will get a spurious "white " line of the paragraph which stops the display adapting to the real last line of the paragraph  and will give bad line and page breaking behaviour.

Comment: what would be a good way to separate things away a little bit? can i replace every \\ with \bigskip? or is there other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is fixed by removing verbatim as @TeXnician suggested and doing the following

```
{\large$${r \choose r} + {r+1 \choose r} + {r+1 \choose r} + ..... + {n 
\choose r} = {n+1 \choose r+1}   $$}:
```

Comment: Note that you're using plain TeX syntax here, in your LaTeX document, see for example [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503). I think `\[
\binom{r}{r} + \binom{r+1}{r} + \binom{r+1}{r} + \dots + \binom{n}{r} = \binom{n+1}{r+1}
\]` would be better.